# How to create a bash script that watches my local git repo and runs 'git log' every time I commit/checkout -b/push/status?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, git, inotify

When I'm coding, I usually have 2 terminal tabs open in VSCode. The tab on the **left** is used for git commands. The tab on the **right** always has `git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline` showing me all the branches and commits.

I'm trying to make it so that the tab on the **right** reruns the `git log` command as soon as I checkout branches, checkout new branches, commit, push, pull...

I tried this:

```
# watchgit.sh
inotifywait -m .git/refs -m .git/HEAD |
    while read dir action file; do
        git log
    done
```

but it doesn't *refresh*. I also don't mind if I get a few extra refreshes here and there.

Would appreciate some help.

Thanks!
[image: My VSCode terminal setup]

Comment: Not really interested in that but I guess I would have a look if I knew the feature you were talking about. The issue also is that this history feature that you're talking about would show up in the VSCode panels themselves. I prefer the terminal windows because I can switch between coding and a full screen display of my 2 terminals side by side with a shortcut; it's really that easy. Whereas the history feature that you're talking about will (likely) take up precious real estate in the VSCode panels themselves, requiring me to do some shifting/resizing. But I'm open to having a look I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look to the bottom right there is the `(END)` this comes from the pager used by git.

There `--no-pager` to avoid this issue

Then do `while` to react to each event around `inotifywait`:

```bsh
while inotifywait .git/refs .git/HEAD ; do                                                             
 git --no-pager log --decorate=short --pretty=oneline
done
```